# No error highlighting for a F# file named test.fsx in VSCode

Tags: f#, ionide

When I open test.fsx in VSCode, it doesn't show error highlighting. If I change its name to Test.fsx or test1.fsx, it works fine. Does test.fsx have special meaning in F# project?

I created F# project file using `dotnet new console --language F#` and added test.fsx under root folder.

- VSCode: 1.45.1
- Ionide: 4.11.1

Both are latest version.

I also have Visual Studio for Mac installed, but it doesn't have such problem.

Comment: test.fsx should not be special. Have you tried moving the file to another folder and then opening the folder in VS Code, just to see it is not something with the folder?

Comment: @JuanTarquino, It only happens if test.fsx is under root folder.